# TypeConverter for a List of Objects

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, typeconverter

I'm trying to create a windows form which uses a property grid to display a list of objects. Right now I have a few classes. The first one, DisplayContainer, simply holds a list of objects and an instance of it acts as the selected object for my property grid

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public class DisplayContainer
    {
        [CategoryAttribute("XRecord Data")]
        public string Name { get; set; } //Name of the collection to uniquely ID it

        [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter)),
        CategoryAttribute("XRecord Data")]
        public List<object> Objects { get; set; } //List of the objects to be manipulated

        public DisplayContainer()
        {
            Objects = new List<object>();
        }
    }
```

The object I'm wanting to store is an instance of my Serialine class

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(SerialineConverter))]
    public class Serialine
    {
        [CategoryAttribute("Points")]
        public Seriapoint FirstPoint { get; set; }
        [CategoryAttribute("Points")]
        public Seriapoint SecondPoint { get; set; }
        [CategoryAttribute("Dimensions"),
        ReadOnlyAttribute(true)]
        public double Length { get; set; }

        public Serialine()
        {

        }

        public Serialine(Seriapoint passedFirstPoint, Seriapoint passedSecondPoint)
        {
            FirstPoint = passedFirstPoint;
            SecondPoint = passedSecondPoint;
            UpdateLength();
        }

        public void UpdateLength()
        {
            double a = FirstPoint.X - SecondPoint.X;
            double b = FirstPoint.Y - SecondPoint.Y;
            double c = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(a, 2) + Math.Pow(b, 2));

            Length = c;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "First Point: " + FirstPoint.ToString() + "; Second Point: " + SecondPoint.ToString() + "; Length: " + Length.ToString() + ";";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pointToParse">String representation of point in the form of (X, Y, Z)</param>
        public static Seriapoint ParsePoint(string pointToParse)
        {
            string[] coordinates = pointToParse.Split(',');
            try
            {
                double xValue = Convert.ToDouble(coordinates[0]);
                double yValue = Convert.ToDouble(coordinates[1]);
                double zValue = Convert.ToDouble(coordinates[2]);

                Seriapoint pointToReturn = new Seriapoint(xValue, yValue, zValue);
                return pointToReturn;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

which uses this converter

```
    public class SerialineConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Type destinationType) 
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(Serialine))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }


        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, System.Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(System.String) && value is Serialine)
            {
                Serialine sl = (Serialine)value; 
                return "Success: " + sl.FirstPoint.ToString() + " to " + sl.SecondPoint.ToString() + " with length " + sl.Length;
            }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }

        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Type sourceType)
        {
            if (sourceType == typeof(string))
                return true;

            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            if (value is string)
            {
                try
                {
                    string s = (string)value;
                    Serialine sl = new Serialine();
                    string[] parameters = s.Split(';');
                    sl.FirstPoint = Serialine.ParsePoint(parameters[0]);
                    sl.SecondPoint = Serialine.ParsePoint(parameters[1]);
                    sl.Length = Convert.ToDouble(parameters[2]);
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Can not convert '" + (string)value + "' to type Serialine");
                }
            }
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }
    }
```

And this class for points

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public class Seriapoint
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public double Z { get; set; }

        public Seriapoint()
        {

        }

        public Seriapoint(double passedX, double passedY, double passedZ)
        {
            X = passedX;
            Y = passedY;
            Z = passedZ;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "(" + Math.Round(X, 2) + ", " + Math.Round(Y, 2) + ", " + Math.Round(Z, 2) + ")";
        }
    }
```

Now, what I'm getting is this:

[image]

But what I want is for dropping down the menu to show the actual objects instead of just a capacity and count for the list. I thought the ExpandableObjectConverter I put over my List objects in DisplayContainer would do that but apparently its not.

Comment: There are several odd things there.  What is the purpose of `DisplayContainer`?  I am guessing `Serialine` objects go in that list?  If so, it should be `List<Serialine>` - a prop grid wont do much with object.  then, your `SerialineConverter ` isnt specified as the TC for that class.  Do you want to be able to add/remove/define Serialine objects in the grid - or just edit them?

Comment: I just want to be able to edit them in the property grid. The purpose of display container is to display the attributes of different types of object but if that isn't possible I can make it specific to serialines. I was just trying to be more generic

Comment: Just get rid of  (or ignore) DisplayContainer.  Set a valid `Serialine` object as the propgrid's `SelectedObject`: http://i.imgur.com/OC4AyBz.png Not much will work like you want (all those other reasons) but now you should be able to refine your question for where you want to start

Comment: I think that you'll need to do a custom UITypeEditor.